# How to create a matrix from a linear map and applying the fundamental theorem of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(P_2(\mathbb R), P_4(\mathbb R))$ is the linear map defined by $T(p) = x^2 p$.

(1). Find the matrix of T with respect to the standard basis.

(2). Verify the fundamental theorem of linear maps.

This is what I have, I was wondering if I’m on the right path, I would greatly apreaciate some help.

(1). Let $\mathcal E =\{1, x, x^2\}$ be a standard basis for $P_2(\mathbb R)$ and let $\mathcal F = \{ x^2, x^3, x^4\}$ be the standard basis for $P_4(\mathbb R)$.

Since $T:$ is defined as $T(p)= x^2 p$,

Then $T(1)=x^2$

$T(x)=x^3$

And $T(x^2)= x^4$, hence we get the matrix T with respect to the standard basis, $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

(2) By applying the fundamental theorem of linear maps we get $dim P_2(\mathbb R) = dim (null T ) + dim (range T)$.

Since $\mathcal E$ is the standard basis for $P_2(\mathbb R)$ then $dim P_2(\mathbb R) = 3$.

Also, since the $dim range T = dim \mathcal F$, then $dim range T = 3$.

Therefore, $3= dim null T + 3 $ hence the $dim null T = 0$.

Comment: $P_2(\mathbb R)$ and $P_4(\mathbb R)$ have the same dimension?

Comment: That one of the parts I’m unsure of. Aren’t the two standard basis correct?

Comment: What is $P_4(\mathbb R)$?  Does it contain $x$?

Comment: If $P_4(\mathbb R)$ is the set of polynomials of degree 4 over $\mathbb{R}$ then the standard basis would be $\{\,1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4\,\}$.